# Displays two values (columns) in the mode of selecting an item from the combobox -VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

**Combobox1** lists two columns of the values of cells **A** and **B** in **Sheet1** Excel. But by choosing one item, only the cell A is displayed (and cell B hidden). How to display ***both values*** in the ***selection mode***?

My VBA Code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim xrg   As Range
Set xrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")
With Me.ComboBox1
  .List = xrg.Value
  .ColumnCount = 2
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply can't

but you can work around it:

- place two text boxes each overlapping one "column" in the combobox value display

[image: textboxes overlapping combobox]

[image]

[image]

- place the following code in the userform code pane:

  ```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
      If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then
          Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.ComboBox1.List(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex, 0)
          Me.TextBox2.Value = Me.ComboBox1.List(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex, 1)
      End If
  End Sub
  ```

(change textboxes name to match your choice)

Comment: @FirstLast, any feedback?